# SQL Offset total row count slow with IN Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pagination

I am using the below SQL code based on another answer. However when including the massive in clause, getting the total count takes too long. If I remove the total count, then the query takes less than 1 second. Is there a more efficient way to get the total row count? The answers I saw were based off of 2013 SQL queries.

```
DECLARE 
    @PageSize INT = 10, 
    @PageNum  INT = 1;

WITH TempResult AS(
    SELECT ID, Name
    FROM Table
     Where ID in ( 1 ,2 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ,10)
), TempCount AS (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS MaxRows FROM TempResult
)
SELECT *
FROM TempResult, 
 TempCount    <----- this is what is slow. Removing this and the query is super fast
ORDER BY TempResult.Name
    OFFSET (@PageNum-1)*@PageSize ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Can you post full table DDL, a script to populate the tables, and the query you're trying to optimize.  Whether there is a faster way to count all the rows is highly dependent on the details of the scenario.  In the general case of an complex query,  counting all the rows is quite expensive, and best avoided.

Comment: What I understand you need to refactor the query. You are fetching 155k records for count and that will appear in each and every row. This is definitely reduce the performance. Is that your requirement to show 155k count in every row.

Comment: @Raj Paliwal  no not for every row i just need the total count once since it pagination i want it to show records the first 22 records out of the total count which in this case is not 155k

Comment: How often does the record count change? Can you get the count in a separate query once and then just re-use it?

Comment: @TerranceJackson what is the count(*) result ?

Comment: Please show us the actual execution plans of the fast query (without `COUNT`) and of the slow query (with `COUNT`). It would also be great if you could show the plan for the Gordon's variant with `COUNT(*) OVER()`. You can use  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ to share the plans.

Comment: Why do you need the ```COUNT``` function at all, when you are counting ids in a clearly defined ```IN``` statement? Obviously the result from the count query equals the number of ids. Which you should know if you define the query manually, and which you can count as a list lenght by a programming, non SQL language, if you are generating the query by a program. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are those ids really consecutive or is that just an example?

Comment: with that syntax, I would guess that your count gets executed once for each row returned by the cte causing slowness.

Comment: Your query purpose appears rather ambiguous.  There is no context to the join to the TempCount and appears as @RajPaliwal mentioned, getting 155k count each time since there is no other criteria. Show a sample of what you EXPECT the output to be providing,  Please edit post and provide example and clarification of count per group.  You want numbers per page, but without better sampling of data, harder to interpret what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Step one for performance related questions is going to be to analyze your table/index structure, and to review the query plans. You haven't provided that information, so I'm going to make up my own, and go from there.

I'm going to assume that you have a heap, with ~10M rows (12,872,738 for me):

```
DECLARE @MaxRowCount bigint = 10000000,
        @Offset      bigint = 0;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #ExampleTable;
CREATE TABLE #ExampleTable
(
  ID   bigint      NOT NULL,
  Name varchar(50) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT NOT NULL
);

WHILE @Offset < @MaxRowCount
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO #ExampleTable
  ( ID, Name )
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL )),
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL ))
      FROM master.dbo.spt_values SV
        CROSS APPLY master.dbo.spt_values SV2;
  SET @Offset = @Offset + ROWCOUNT_BIG();
END;
```

If I run the query provided over `#ExampleTable`, it takes about 4 seconds and gives me this query plan:

[image: Baseline query plan]

This isn't a great query plan by any means, but it is hardly awful. Running with live query stats shows that the cardinality estimates were at most off by one, which is fine.

Lets give a massive number of items in our `IN` list (5000 items from 1-5000). Compiling the plan took 4 seconds:

[image: Large IN list query plan]

I can get my number up to 15000 items before the query processor stops being able to handle it, with no change in query plan (it does take a total of 6 seconds to compile). Running both queries takes about 5 seconds a pop on my machine.

This is probably fine for analytical workloads or for data warehousing, but for OLTP like queries we've definitely exceeded our ideal time limit.

Lets look at some alternatives. We can probably do some of these in combination.

1. We could cache off the `IN` list in a temp table or table variable.
2. We could use a window function to calculate the count
3. We could cache off our CTE in a temp table or table variable
4. If on a sufficiently high SQL Server version, use batch mode
5. Change the indices on your table to make this faster.

#### Workflow considerations

If this is for an OLTP workflow, then we need something that is fast regardless of how many users we have. As such, we want to minimize recompiles and we want index seeks wherever possible. If this is analytic or warehousing, then recompiles and scans are probably fine.

If we want OLTP, then the caching options are probably off the table. Temp tables will always force recompiles, and table variables in queries that rely on a good estimate require you to force a recompile. The alternative would be to have some other part of your application maintain a persistent table that has paginated counts or filters (or both), and then have this query join against that.

If the same user would look at many pages, then caching off part of it is probably still worth it even in OLTP, but make sure you measure the impact of many concurrent users.

Regardless of workflow, updating indices is probably okay (unless your workflows are going to really mess with your index maintenance).

Regardless of workflow, batch mode will be your friend.

Regardless of workflow, window functions (especially with either indices and/or batch mode) will probably be better.

#### Batch mode and the default cardinality estimator

We pretty consistently get poor cardinality estimates (and resulting plans) with the legacy cardinality estimator and row-mode executions. Forcing the default cardinality estimator helps with the first, and batch-mode helps with the second.

If you can't update your database to use the new cardinality estimator wholesale, then you'll want to enable it for your specific query. To accomplish that, you can use the following query hint: `OPTION( USE HINT( 'FORCE_DEFAULT_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION' ) )` to get the first. For the second, add a join to a CCI (doesn't need to return data): `LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.EmptyCciForRowstoreBatchmode ON 1 = 0` - this enables SQL Server to pick batch mode optimizations. These recommendations assume a sufficiently new SQL Server version.

What the CCI is doesn't matter; we like to keep an empty one around for consistency, that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.EmptyCciForRowstoreBatchmode
(
  __zzDoNotUse int NULL,
  INDEX CCI CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE
);
```

The best plan I could get without modifying the table was to use both of them. With the same data as before, this runs in <1s.

[image: Batch Mode and NCE]

```
WITH TempResult AS
(
  SELECT ID,
         Name,
         COUNT( * ) OVER ( ) MaxRows
    FROM #ExampleTable
    WHERE ID IN ( <<really long LIST>> )
)
  SELECT TempResult.ID,
         TempResult.Name,
         TempResult.MaxRows
    FROM TempResult
      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.EmptyCciForRowstoreBatchmode ON 1 = 0
    ORDER BY TempResult.Name OFFSET ( @PageNum - 1 ) * @PageSize ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
    OPTION( USE HINT( 'FORCE_DEFAULT_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION' ) );
```

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know there are 3 ways to achieve this, besides using the #temp table approach already mentioned. In my test cases below, I've used a SQL Server 2016 Developer instance with 6CPU/16GB RAM, and a simple table containing ~25M rows.

**Method 1: CROSS JOIN**

```
DECLARE
  @PageSize INT = 10
, @PageNum  INT = 1;

WITH TempResult AS (SELECT
                          id
                        , shortDesc
                    FROM  dbo.TestName
                    WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
SELECT
           *, MaxRows
FROM       TempResult
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(1) AS MaxRows FROM TempResult) AS TheCount
ORDER BY   TempResult.shortDesc OFFSET (@PageNum - 1) * @PageSize ROWS 
FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;
```

Test result 1:

[image]

**Method 2: COUNT(*) OVER()**

```
DECLARE
  @PageSize INT = 10
, @PageNum  INT = 1;

WITH TempResult AS (SELECT
                          id
                        , shortDesc
                    FROM  dbo.TestName
                    WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
)
SELECT
         *, MaxRows = COUNT(*) OVER()
FROM     TempResult
ORDER BY TempResult.shortDesc OFFSET (@PageNum - 1) * @PageSize ROWS
FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;
```

Test result 2:

[image]

**Method 3: 2nd CTE**

Test result 3 (T-SQL used was the same as in the question):

[image]

**Conclusion**

The fastest method depends on your data structure (and total number of rows) in combination with your server sizing/load. In my case using COUNT(*) OVER() proved to be the fastest method. To find what is best for you, you have to test what is best for your scenario. And don't rule out that #table approach either just yet ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to count the rows **while** filtering the table using `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
DECLARE 
    @PageSize INT = 10, 
    @PageNum  INT = 1;

;WITH 
TempResult AS (
    SELECT ID, Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) N
    FROM Table
    Where ID in ( 1 ,2 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ,10)
), 
TempCount AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 N AS MaxRows 
    FROM TempResult
    ORDER BY ID DESC
)
SELECT *
FROM 
    TempResult, 
    TempCount 
ORDER BY 
    TempResult.Name
    OFFSET (@PageNum-1)*@PageSize ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try phrasing this as:

```
WITH TempResult AS(
      SELECT ID, Name, COUNT(*) OVER () as maxrows
      FROM Table
      Where ID in ( 1 ,2 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ,10)
     )
```

However, I doubt that you will see much performance improvement.  The entire table needs to be scanned to get the total count.  That is probably where the performance issue is.

Comment: Yea just tried that. It cut the time down from 6 seconds to 3. Of course removing it completely its less than 1 second. I wish there was a faster way to scan a table instantly

Comment: The fastest way to scan a table is to use a columnstore index: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft . . . Assuming the table has more columns than `id` and `name`.  But that begs the question, an index on `(id, name)` should work just as well.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft  So i changed to a columnstore and the performance was still the same. The count is 155k records. I have an index on 3 columns in that table and there is one join in the query. That joined table also has an index on the same columns being joined. There has to be a better way to get the count in a pagination offset query

Answer (score 1):

This might be a shot in the dark but you can try using a *temp table* instead of a *cte*.
Though the performance results and preference of one over the other depends on use-case to use-case, a *temp table* sometimes can actually prove better since it enables you to leverage indices and dedicated statistics.

```
INSERT INTO #TempResult 
    SELECT ID, Name
    FROM Table
    WHERE ID in ( 1 ,2 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ,10)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `IN` statement is a notorious hurdle for the SQL Server query engine. When it gets "massive" (your words) it slows down even simple queries. In my experience, `IN` statements with more than 5000 items nearly always unacceptably slow down any query.

It nearly always works better to convert the items of a large `IN` statement into a temp table or table variable first and then join with this table, as below. I tested this and found it's significantly faster, even with the preparation of the temp table. I think that the `IN` statement, even though the inner query performs well enough with it, has a detrimental effect on the combined query.

```sql
DECLARE @ids TABLE (ID int primary key );

-- This must be done in chunks of 1000
INSERT @ids (ID) VALUES
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),...
...

;WITH TempResult AS
(
    SELECT tbl.ID, tbl.Name
    FROM Table tbl
    JOIN @ids ids ON ids.ID = tbl.ID
),
TempCount AS 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS MaxRows FROM TempResult
)
SELECT *
FROM TempResult, 
     TempCount
ORDER BY TempResult.Name
    OFFSET (@PageNum-1)*@PageSize ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: The main issue with a table variable is that now you're going to have to force a recompile (as you almost certainly are going to depend on cardinality estimates in this scenario). Temp tables aren't necessarily any better here, but it is less than ideal

Comment: @Dannnno Of course a temp table could also be used here. But admittedly, I didn't investigate execution plans as thoroughly as you did, for which upvoted your answer yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

CTEs are very nice, but having many consecutive CTEs (two is not many I think but in general) caused me many times performace horror. The simplest method I think would be calculate number of rows once and assign it to variable:

```
DECLARE 
    @PageSize INT = 10, 
    @PageNum  INT = 1,
    @MaxRows bigint = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Table Where ID in ( 1 ,2 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ,10));

WITH TempResult AS(
    SELECT ID, Name
    FROM Table
     Where ID in ( 1 ,2 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ,10)
)
SELECT *
FROM TempResult, 
 @MaxRows TempCount    <----- this is what is slow. Removing this and the query is super fast
ORDER BY TempResult.Name
    OFFSET (@PageNum-1)*@PageSize ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this at the moment but on glancing through it struck me that specifying a multiply (cross join) as in:

```
FROM TempResult, 
 TempCount    <----- this is what is slow. Removing this and the query is super
```

may be the issue

How does it perform when written simply as:

```
DECLARE 
    @PageSize INT = 10, 
    @PageNum  INT = 1;

WITH TempResult AS(
    SELECT ID, Name
    FROM Table
     Where ID in ( 1 ,2 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ,10)
)
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TempResult) AS MaxRows
FROM TempResult
ORDER BY TempResult.Name
    OFFSET (@PageNum-1)*@PageSize ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
```